# Error On Setting Up SMTP On Ofiice365 On Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, office365

When I am trying to set up SMTP mail account which my client gave there is an error where i could resolve ,

Can someone help

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls used STARTTLS & ssl
```

This is the error that i get

```
Swift_TransportException
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "appointments@test.org" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more info. [SG2PR04CA0177.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com] ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "451", with message "451 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX4 [SG2PR04CA0177.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com] ".
```

Can someone help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/5-7-139-authentication-unsuccessful-error-suddenly/

> Someone disabled SMTP for the box you have a link with an explanation
> in the error you posted.
>
> One way to try:
>
> Use the Microsoft 365 admin center to enable or disable SMTP AUTH on
> specific mailboxes Open the Microsoft 365 admin center and go to Users
>
> > Active users.
>
> Select the user, and in the flyout that appears, click Mail.
>
> In the Email apps section, click Manage email apps.
>
> Verify the Authenticated SMTP setting: unchecked = disabled, checked =
> enabled.
>
> When you're finished, click Save changes.